# Django haystack search result possible to get list of actual objects directly?

Tags: django, django-haystack

Normally django haystack search result is a list of 'result' object, in order to get to the actual object I need to use `result.object`

Which makes reusing the normal list template impossible, eg.

```
{% for item in object_list %}
  {{ item.title }}  # in search result {{ item.object.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a built-in method I can use to work around this problem or I need to write a custom search view to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I used `{% with generic_item=item.object|default:item %}` then `{{ generic_item.whatever }}` from then on